# Not Set Value in form_hidden codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter

I have a problem I can not understand.
I need a hidden field on my form, but I can not put the value returned from my session.

My code:

```
echo form_hidden('redirect', $this->session->userdata('redir_para'));
```

Output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
```

My debug:

```
echo $this->session->userdata('redir_para');
echo form_hidden('redirect', $this->session->userdata('redir_para'));
```

Output:

```
http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/gerenciar
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
```

More debug:

```
$data = array(
        'redirect'  => $this->session->userdata('redir_para'),
        'email' => 'john@example.com',
        'url'   => 'http://example.com'
    );
```

Output:

```
<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" />
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="john@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://example.com" />
```

Not understand why does not work!

Thanks!!

Answer (score 0):

You have to define a variable first, like this:

```
$redirect = $this->session->userdata('redir_para');

var_dump($redirect); // Debug, not needed

echo form_hidden('redirect', $redirect);

$data = array(
    'redirect'  => $redirect,
    'email' => 'john@example.com',
    'url'   => 'http://example.com'
);
```

Comment: Okay, and if you do this: `var_dump($redirect)`, what does it output?

Comment: output this: string 'http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/gerenciar' (length=48)

Comment: Very strange, and what does it output when you do this: `echo form_hidden('redir', $redirect);` instead of `echo form_hidden('redirect', $redirect);`?

Comment: same problem using `echo form_hidden('redir', $redirect); `

Comment: i'm using the version 2.2

Comment: It might be a bug, I can't find the problem.

Answer (score 0):

News debug:

```
    $http = "http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/login";

    $data = array(
        'redirect'  => $http,
        'email' => 'john@example.com',
        'url'   => 'http://example.com'
    );

    var_dump($data);

    echo form_hidden($data);
```

Output:

```
array (size=3)
    'redirect' => string 'http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/login' (length=44)
    'email' => string 'john@example.com' (length=16)
    'url' => string 'http://example.com' (length=18)

<input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/login" 
<input type="hidden" name="email" value="john@example.com" />
<input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://example.com" />
```

Its works!! :)

Other test:

```
 $redirect = $this->session->userdata('redir_para');
 var_dump($redirect);

 $data = array(
     'redirect'  => $redirect,
     'email' => 'john@example.com',
     'url'   => 'http://example.com'
 );

 var_dump($data);
 echo form_hidden($data);
```

Output:

```
string 'http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/gerenciar' (length=48)

array (size=3)
    'redirect' => string 'http://cipainel.dev/index.php/usuarios/gerenciar' (length=48)
    'email' => string 'john@example.com' (length=16)
    'url' => string 'http://example.com' (length=18)

 <input type="hidden" name="redirect" value="" 
 <input type="hidden" name="email" value="john@example.com" />
 <input type="hidden" name="url" value="http://example.com" />
```

I'm going crazy with this. :(